# Breaking page inheritance programatically in sharepoint 2010

Tags: permissions

I have certain page in SharePoint where i need to break inheritance remove certain security groups form the permissions permanently.Al i want to do is through programatically to be done.Please suggest any ideas on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can follow this post:
[Assigning SharePoint List Item level permission programmatically](http://www.thespgeek.com/2011/08/assigning-sharepoint-list-item-level.html)

Excerpt from article:

> **RemoveAllPermissions Function**
>
> ```
> private static void RemoveAllPermissions(SPListItem CurrentlistItem)
>     {
>         //The below function Breaks the role assignment inheritance for the list and gives the current list its own copy of the role assignments
>         CurrentlistItem.BreakRoleInheritance(true);
>         //Get the list of Role Assignments to list item and remove one by one.
>         SPRoleAssignmentCollection SPRoleAssColn = CurrentlistItem.RoleAssignments;
>         for (int i = SPRoleAssColn.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
>         {
>             SPRoleAssColn.Remove(i);
>         }
>     }
> ```
>
> **GrantPermission Function**
>
> ```
> private static void GrantPermission(SPListItem CurrentListItem, SPWeb oSPWeb, SPRoleType SPRoleType, SPPrincipal SPPrincipal)
>     {
>         try
>         {
>             //Create one Role Definition i.e Full Controls, Contribute rights or Read rights etc.
>             SPRoleDefinition oSPRoleDefinition = oSPWeb.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(SPRoleType);
>             //Create one Role Assignment for the specified SP user or group.
>             SPRoleAssignment oSPRoleAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment(SPPrincipal);
>             //Bind the role definition to the role assignment object created for the user or group.
>             oSPRoleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(oSPRoleDefinition);
>             //Add it to the specified list item.
>             CurrentListItem.RoleAssignments.Add(oSPRoleAssignment);
>             //update the list item so that specified user assignment will have the access.
>             CurrentListItem.Update();
>         }
>         catch (Exception ex)
>         {
>             EventLog.WriteEntry("Error in UAR Initiation Workflow", "GrantPermission() : " + ex.Message);
>         }
>     }
> ```

You can get the List Item for `SPFile` using `SPFile.Item`

Comment: HI Adam i want to break permissions for page not list.Can you please suggest.

Comment: Yes Page is actually an item of Document Library.. you can get the page list item by `SPFile.Item` property !